# How to remove Ubuntu from boot screen?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I tried to install **Ubuntu 14.04** on my **Windows 8**, and in the installation wizard I chose "Help me boot from CD". Now I have something like this when I restart the computer:

[image]

If I click Ubuntu I get an error about a missing file (wubildr.mbr). I found a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported). But that's not my concern now.

I don't know if that means I have Ubuntu installed on my computer now or not, but I wanna delete it from the boot screen.

I figured that I need to delete its partition, so I went to **Disk Management** and found the following:

[image]

My question is: which one should I delete?

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu!  The simple answer to your question is Delete none of them. It sound like you tried to install using wubi. (not recommended) If this is indeed the case you can likely use windows 8 to remove it from the program list. Or follow the manufacturers restore instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one. You didn't created any Ubuntu partition. All that partitions are created by Windows, if you delete any of them you can loose data, render Windows unusable or destroy your computer ability to reinstall Windows.

You tried to install Ubuntu using [WUBI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_%28Ubuntu_installer%29), a special kind of installation that installs Ubuntu inside Windows. It's not compatible with Windows 8.

You should be able to uninstall Ubuntu using the Windows Control Panel.